# Zend App is not working after deployment. Can access only the homepage

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, deployment, webserver, web-deployment

I can access the homepage and can get the data from the database. There everything seems OK. But when I try to go to another page from my application I am redirected to `404 error page`. The URL which is showing at the bottom left corner on my browser when hover the link seems ok.  It is as should be.

I tried to change the `.htaccess` file on the server from:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /
```

To:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But it fails again. Tried different combinations. For example change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /projectname/public/` or `RewriteBase /projectname/`. Still no success.

Of course, I am not sure if the `.htaccess` is the problem. May be something different but I have no idea what...

On localhost the application is working and everything is OK there.

**Edit:** After several changes that I try I finally get it working.

### ***Here is the solution:***

I leaved server's .htaccess file as is. So it has only `RewriteBase /` on it. 
Then on the first line of my .htaccess file (which is in the `projectname/public` folder) I added this:

```
RewriteBase /projectname/public
```

Now everything is working.

Comment: Your production domain is poiting to wich directory ? your htacces and index.php are in wich directory too ? you are still in developement environement s othat you can see better details on errors ?

Comment: I think this will help you    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362670/zend-framework-only-index-view-renders-404-error-when-trying-to-access-other-vi/12367014

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solution**

Leave server's .htaccess file as is. So there is only `RewriteBase /` in it. 
Then on the first line of application's .htaccess file (which is in the `projectname/public` folder) add this line:

```
RewriteBase /projectname/public
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain name (your url) has to point to `/projectname/public/` and you won't need to add anything in your `.htaccess` file.
As an example, here is my own `.htaccess` file (generated when creating my project via `Zend_Tool`). I need no `RewriteBase` ! :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```