# Zend Framework: only index view renders 404 error when trying to access other views via /controller/action url

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I am new to Zend Framework.

I am running Apache 2.2 and have set the DocumentRoot in the httpd.conf file to the public directory created using Zend_Tool.

Within the public directory I have an .htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

...and an index.php file;

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
/*defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || */define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

When I type "http://localhost/" into the browser the file index.phtml in the "application/views/scripts/index/" directory is rendered ok.

If I try to access other views using the controller and action names in a url I get a 404 error saying that the requested URL could not be found on the server.

For example I have the controller file TestController.php 
which is in the same directory as IndexController.php

/*TestController.php*/

```
<?php

class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        // action body
    }


}
```

I have created a test directory containing a file called index.phtml in "application/views/scripts/";

/*views/scripts/test/index.phtml*/

```
<br /><br />
<div id="view-content">
<p>View script for controller <b>Test</b> and script/action name <b>index</b></p>
</div>
```

When I try to render this file by typing "http://localhost/test/" I get a 404 error stating that the requested URL could not be found. All of the Zend Framework documentation I have read and countless other resources all state that this method should render correctly.

I must be missing something, but after an exhaustive search have been unable to find anyone else having this particular problem.

Regards Roan

Answer (score 1):

try creating an indexAction in the test controller... or test.phtml in the directory

Comment: My appologies this error was from me playing around with the action and phtml names to try to figure out the problem. I have changed the action name in TestController.php back to indexAction and the file in the test directory to index.phtml, but "http://localhost/test" still returns a 404 error

Comment: Could there be a problem with my server configuration? The index.phtml file renders ok if I type "http://localhost", but not if I type "http://localhost/index" or "http://localhost/index/index". All the documentation I have read say this should work

Comment: @user1661725 ok try creating a new action in the index controller say anotherAction() then also create view in the view/scripts/index/another.phtml see if it works. If it works then everything seems alright you must recheck for typo/correct directory paths etc

Comment: Turns out it was the AllowOverride directive in my httpd.conf file for apache. The value was set to None. I changed this to All, restarted apache and all working ok!

Comment: nice that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the second url localhost/test is going through your index.php.
You can put a die() or some debug statement for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try to add this in your httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot Link to yourSiteFolder exp. C:/AppServ/www/yourSite/public
ServerName youServerName exp. http://mysite.com or you ip http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 </VirtualHost>

<Directory "Link to yourSiteFolder exp. C:/AppServ/www/yourSite/public">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Find this:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And delete '#'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.

Thought I would post my solution for others..

Here is the section I updated in the httpd.conf file within the directory tags;

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

and I had previously uncommented the module mentioned above

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Cheers